# JQuery not Functioning Properly in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, syntax, version

I want to start this question by saying yes, I have visited other questions like this one. I have been troubleshooting this for a while now, and finally decided my problem has something these others don't. So here we go.

I've got this code from someone here that works great in Jsfiddle, and I want to add it to my website. I'm a huge noob, and have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to javascript, but I am starting to learn. Here's the code, and the website page it's not working on.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#filterDiv').on("change keyup", function() {
    chkBox = {
      datatest: null
    };

    if ($('#3').is(':checked')) {
      chkBox.datatest = "1";
    } else {
      chkBox.datatest = "";
    }

    $("p").hide().filter(function() {
      var rtnData = "";

      regExName = new RegExp($('#0').val().trim(), "ig");
      regExA = new RegExp($('#1').val().trim(), "ig");
      regExB = new RegExp($('#2').val().trim(), "ig");
      regExTest = new RegExp(chkBox.datatest, "ig")

      rtnData = (
        $(this).attr("data-name").match(regExName) &&
        $(this).attr("data-a").match(regExA) &&
        $(this).attr("data-b").match(regExB) &&
        $(this).attr("data-test").match(regExTest)
      );

      //console.log(rtnData);
      return rtnData;
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.mySel {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.myInput {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.ps {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #0072ff;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.aBlue {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

.bYellow {
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.cGreen {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.eagle {
  border-radius: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="filterDiv">
  <input type="text" class="myInput" id="0" />

  <select class="mySel" id="1">
    <option value="">Session</option>
    <option value="1">1st</option>
    <option value="2">2nd</option>
    <option value="3">3rd</option>
    <option value="4">4th</option>
  </select>

  <select class="mySel" id="2">
    <option value="">Area</option>
    <option value="beach">Beach</option>
    <option value="tower">Tower</option>
    <option value="ods">Outdoor Skills</option>
    <option value="fca">First Class Adventure</option>
    <option value="central">Central Program</option>
    <option value="hc">Handicrafts</option>
    <option value="nc">Nature Center</option>
    <option value="sc">South Commissioner</option>
    <option value="range">Rifle/Shotgun Range</option>
  </select>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3"> Eagle Required?
</div>
<p class="ps bYellow eagle" data-name="camping" data-a="12" data-b="central" data-test="1">Camping 2SESSION</p>
<p class="ps cGreen" data-name="climbing" data-a="23" data-b="tower" data-test="">Climbing 2SESSION</p>
<p class="ps cGreen" data-name="pioneering" data-a="3" data-b="ods" data-test="">Pioneering</p>
<p class="ps aBlue eagle" data-name="swimming" data-a="4" data-b="beach" data-test="1">Swimming</p>
<p class="ps bYellow eagle" data-name="weather" data-a="1" data-b="nc" data-test="">Weather</p>
<p class="ps cGreen" data-name="woodcarving" data-a="2" data-b="hc" data-test="">Woodcarving</p>
```

Here's the problem webpage: http://35.184.94.78/index.php/programs/archery-range/
When you select any option, or type in the search everything disappears and you get a "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" error. I've seen a lot of people with this problem have the wrong syntax, but it's working fine in JSfiddle so I don't think that error is the actual problem.

Here's the confusing part, Wordpress, if you've ever worked with it, is really picky about adding script. So I installed a plugin called Scripts n' Styles which can add code in very easily along with calling jQuery with just a dropdown. Another thing I learned is that this code has to load after the page has loaded, so I made sure to have this inserted after the /body tag. Also, Wordpress doesn't like the jQuery "$" and they want you to say "jQuery" instead. So I found if you wrap it in that "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {" then it will act normally.

I started with this not doing anything, but after all these weird fixes it finally is doing something, but unfortunately that something is erroring out and disappearing entirely.

Here's my last lead. I think it has something to do with conflicting versions of jquery being loaded, since I have some other plugins that use jquery. So my next attack was to try and de-register the other jquery versions before this one is loaded, but I can't figure out how to do that in Wordpress, let alone do it nicely so the other plugin's aren't effected.

I have been straight up learning all of this from W3Schools for the past 3 months, so I'm very sorry if this is a stupid question. I've just been trying to get this to work, so sorry for the stupid data names and class names.

Comment: EDIT: I have now realized that this little snippet isn't only looking at the <p> I want it to look at, it's looking at ALL <p>'s. How can I direct the jQuery to only look at the <p> to hide that I want?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, I should just use a class selector instead. I was trying to use an ID selector but that wasn't working either. All I did to fix this was change $( 'p' ) to $( '.ps) to select the ps class instead of all the p elements.